# How can I replace a specific character in one string, with a specific character from another string?

Tags: bash, command-line

For example: I have `string1 = 'abcd'`, and `string2 = 'xwyz'`.

I want to replace the 3rd character of string1 ('c') with the 4th character of string2 ('z').

Of course, string indexing starts from 0.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11):

With **bash** substring manipulation:

```
s1="abcd"
s2="xwyz"
s1=${s1:0:2}${s2:3}${s1:3}
```

- `${s1:0:2}` - the 1st slice containing `ab` (till the 3rd character `c`)
- `${s2:3}` - the 4th character of the `s2` string to be inserted
- `${s1:3}` - the last (4th) character of the `s1` string

---

Final `s1` value:

```
echo $s1
abzd
```

---

Or with GNU **awk** tool:

```
gawk -v s2=$s2 -v FPAT='[a-z]' '{$3=substr(s2,4)}1' OFS="" <<< $s1
abzd
```

---

- `<<< $s1` - the first string `s1` is considered as input content
- `-v s2=$s2` - passing the second string `s2` as a variable into *awk* script
- `FPAT='[a-z]'` - regex pattern defining a field value (`[a-z]` - any alphabetic character)

---

Alternatively, you could also apply the "empty" field separator `FS=""` treating each character as separate field:

```
gawk -v s2=$s2 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="" }{$3=substr(s2,4)}1' <<< $s1
abzd
```

Comment: OP asked for the 3rd character of `sc2` which would be `${s2:2:1}` although they then proceed to use the 4th in the example. In any case it would be more suitable to slice exactly 1 character and not the entire trailing string since there's not explicit length limit of 4. Otherwise +1.

Comment: You can just use `-F ''` if you want each character to be a field. The space is necessary for some versions of awk.

Comment: @TomFenech, added as alternative

Answer (score 3):

Here is awk code (long and complicated, but work for me)

```
echo |awk -v a="$string1" -v b="$string2" '{split(a,a1,""); n=split(b,b1,"");a1[2]=b1[3];for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {printf a1[i]}}'
```

Comment: Rather than echoing an empty line, you can just put the logic inside the `BEGIN` block. Maybe it's fine here but personally I'd always quote those variables too.

Comment: Of course quoting variables is good practice, will edit the answer :)